# Matlab: Finding the permutation matrices that produce another matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, permutation, combinatorics

I'm trying to write MATLAB code that will allow me to find the permutation matrices of a matrix.

Let's consider the example below. I'm given the matrices `A` and `B`:

```
A = [1 2 3;4 5 6; 7 8 9]   % is a given matrix
B = [9 7 8;3 1 2; 6 4 5]   % is a permuted version of A.
```

My goal is to find the matrices `L` (that pre-multiply `A`) and `R` (that post-multiply `A`) such that `L*A*R = B`:

```
% L is an n by n (3 by 3) that re-order the rows a matrix when it pre-multiply that matrix
L = [0 0 1;1 0 0;0 1 0] 

% R is an n by n that re-order the columns of a matrix
R = [0 1 0;0 0 1;1 0 0] 

B = L*A*R
```

How to find `L` and `R` when I know `A` and `B`?

Comment: this is quite likely more suitable on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give a baseline solution, here is the brute-force method:

```
function [L,R] = find_perms(A,B)
    [n,n] = size(A);
    p = perms(1:n);
    I = eye(n);
    for i=1:size(p,1)
        for j=1:size(p,1)
            L = I(p(i,:),:);
            R = I(:,p(j,:));
            if isequal(L*A*R, B)
                return;
            end
        end
    end
    % none found
    L = [];
    R = [];
end
```

Let's test it:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
B = [9 7 8; 3 1 2; 6 4 5];
[L,R] = find_perms(A,B);
assert(isequal(L*A*R, B));
```

The left/right permutation matrices are as expected:

```
>> L
L =
     0     0     1
     1     0     0
     0     1     0
>> R
R =
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
     1     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually copied and pasted your code in Matlab and this is the answer that I've got and I don't know why it says that.Thanks again for the reply.                                                                 "Error: File: experience.m Line: 3 Column: 1
Function definitions are not permitted in this context.""FUNCTION keyword use is invalid here".